# Rolling back only some records during the update

Tags: apex, soap-api, record-type, person-accounts

I am updating and inserting some records in salesforce, through a SOAP API service.

The procedure, corresponds to a simple update or insert to the fields of an Account record. It is required to handle the use case, where a Business Account(record type), changes into a Person Account(the standard record type, that gets activated, by salesforce, on your demand), or vice versa.

Due to the special nature of Person Accounts RT, I have designed the class, so it first sets the record type(FIRST DML OP), and then I commit in the database the other info of account records, in a second moment(i.e. Phone, email etc.)(SECOND DML OP).

Before commiting the second DML OP, i perform some data validation, according to the data received from the SOAP Request.

What I need, is a logic, that rolls back, the records modified in the FIRST DML OP, if they fail the custom validation, that I have specified, before the SECOND DML OP.

I've thought about using Database.SavePoint() & Database.Rollback(), but that rolls back all the records validated successfully. I want only to roll back, the update of the record type, for the records not validated.

> Note:
>
> Q: Why do I set the record type, separately, in a first DML
>   operation?
>
> A: Because, if you want to change the record type, from a person
>   account, to another record type, or vice versa, you have to do it
>   separately. Than you modify the fields, accordingly, to your business
>   logic. This is workaround is also the only way suggested by Salesforce.

Comment: I did this once using a custom rollback method that did a manual DML delete of the records that failed the validation at step 2 while allowing the records that passed step2 validation to proceed to the update DML.  You have to make sure you wrap everything in try-catches so no exception goes uncaught.  A wrapper class on the incoming Accounts is helpful so you can easily mark the list of wrapped accounts as to which ones passed/failed the validation

Comment: of course - one could ask why you can't do the validation before the first dml op if the data exists in the soap request

Comment: Actually I figured out a cleaner way, inlcuding triggers in the show.


Something like:
- If RT gets changed in the FIRST DML. => Remember the old RT.

- So if a record fails my custom validation(this is defined by my business logic), retrieve the old record type, and perform a "rollback" update of the record type.

*The problem is that I am struggling to detect a Record type change on the account, when I am going from Business Account <-> Person Account. 


**It's strange because I am able to detect a change from Another Type of Account <-> Business Account, but not the first one.

Comment: your solution is essentially what I suggested except you retain the row rather than deleting it - if that is what your business logic says to do, works for me!